# Edit a string in a file

Tags: android, file, edit

Is possible to edit a string in a file programmatically?
For example, i've a file named /sdcard/myfile that contains:

```
somestrings
otherstrings=lajd
ecc... abcdefghilmondj conf=300
```

I want replace conf=300 with conf=100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) for replacing the contents of the file inplace.

sed -i 's/conf=300/conf=100/g' /sdcard/myfile

Make sure you have sufficient permissions to modify /sdcard/myfile.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Scanner` class to load the file, line by line. Look for the sub-string conf=300. Replace, it with conf=100. Save everything back to the file.